# How to select count distinct in DolphinDB？

Tags: sql, database, time-series, dolphindb

I would like to execute the following SQL query in DolphinDB.

```
select count(distinct symbol) from loadTable("dfs://share","stock1")
```

It throws an exception Can't call an aggregated function in the argument of another aggregated function call.

Is my query wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like below using subquery

```
 select count(*) from (
 select distinct symbol from loadTable("dfs://share","stock1")
  ) a
```